# Regular expression does not pick up middle group

Tags: php, regex, pcre

The (PHP) regular expression is:

```
"/\b(screen|front|glass|lcd)\b.*?\b(not)?\b.*?\b(replaced|cracked|broken|chipped)\b/i"
```

The intent is for the regular expression to match both :

```
"screen is not cracked"
"screen is cracked"
```

and pick up the NOT if present as the second group. However it seems that the second group is empty for both the above sample input.

What am I doing wrong?

Tip: I'm testing this using http://www.regexe.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the first non-greedy quantifier in an optional group with the word "not":

```
\b(screen|front|glass|lcd)\b(?:.*?\b(not)\b)?.*?\b(replaced|cracked|broken|chipped)\b
```

So `\b(not)\b` is no more optional inside the non-capturing group and the non-greedy quantifier makes its job and stops once "not" is reached.

An optimized way, that lazily grabs words until *cracked/chipped/replaced/broken* and eventually captures "not":

```
\b(screen|front|glass|lcd)\W+(?>(?:(not)|\w+)\W+)*?(?=[crb])(c(?:racked|hipped)|replaced|broken)\b
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `.*?` before the pattern which matches the optional not will also match the `not` greedily. For this case, you need to use negative lookahead.

```
(screen|front|glass|lcd)(?:(?!\bnot\b).)*(not)?.*?(replaced|cracked|broken|chipped)
```

`(?:(?!\bnot\b).)*` would check for the  character going to be matched won't be the starting letter in the string `not`. If yes, then it will match the following character. Else, it won't match the following character thus resulting in an empty match (*because of `*`*).

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yH3eV5/1)

Comment: yep, it's non-greedy. Because the not is optional, non-greedy part matches also the `not` string.

Comment: regex101.com That is an awesome site, I wasn't aware of. Thank you!

Comment: This is a great answer and works but based on efficiency I will accept @casimir-et-hippolyte, which also works and the regex is slightly easier to follow.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the "is" word

```
m!\b(screen|front|glass|lcd)\b *is *\b(not\b)?(replaced|cracked|broken|chipped)\b!i
```

Comment: no those are just simple example strings. It should match things like "screen perfect and not cracked", which is why the .*? I don't really know how a user will describe the screen, but I am interested in the key words that will give me the gist of what they are saying.